# Is there a way to RDP into a laptop and still use its monitor as a second screen?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, vnc

To be precise, in my case, a third screen. My setup is the following:

I have a personal computer with two monitors. I also have a work laptop on my left. I usually RDP from my personal computer to my laptop so I don't have to reroute all my monitor cables to a dock on the laptop. However, the laptop screen blacks out when I RDP.

I was wondering if there was a way to keep the screen active as a third screen.

Comment: You need to log off the machine you are accessing by RDP.  Now RDP should log it off, then make the connection.  You can put Radmin Server on the target machine and access it with Radmin Viewer. I use this.

Comment: I think your answer is no if I understand the question correctly.  VNC will probably provide what you are asking for but I am a bit confused about the question.  VNC can leave the screen active while remotely logged in.  The performance is not as good as RDC but do-able.

Comment: I do not want to simply mirror the display, but extend it to all my screens. RDP allows me to "create" a second screen from my laptop to my two monitors plugged into the client (my PC). What I would like is to be able to still have the laptop screen usable then

Comment: I do not think you can extend screens with RDP. You can put the Apps you need in the target computer and run the Apps that way.

Comment: Sadly, using my PC instead of my laptop is not an option. I need to use the laptop, and I use RDP to do so from my PC for convenience. I would like more convenience by having the laptop's screen also available to me instead of being on the lock screen all the time.

Comment: You probably should get a portable screen for your situation

Comment: If you're after basically controlling the laptop via the PC's keyboard and mouse, but continuing to use the laptop display there are a few options, for instance Mouse Without Borders, which lets you move mouse etc from one to the other like they were a single machine (and share clipboard etc across them). There are reviews of various options online, for instance https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-control-multiple-computers-with-one-keyboard-and-mouse